# C7206VXR Can I run an NPE-G1 and NPE-G2 card concurrently to get more GigE ports?

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-7200

I have a 7206VXR that I need to have 2 ports gigE for WAN (2 ISPs) and to upgrade from the 4 100M ports to 3 gig ports for LAN. I have an NPE-G1 installed currently. Is it possible to *add* an NPE-G2 port and to be able to route between ports on both cards concurrently? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Cisco 7206VXR only has a single NPE (Network Processing Engine) slot. You can choose to have one or the other.

Comment: Okay, thanks Ron. Looks like 2 PA-GE are in order then.

Comment: You want to be careful of the slots in which you put them. There is a points method for slot use, and you are going to need to balance between odd and even numbered slots.

Comment: dang. okay. If you happen to have a reference handy that you can pass on that'd be great.

Comment: n/m, found it. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Just search for Cisco 7200 bandwidth points. Cisco has documentation about this. It has been years, but I remember need to calculate this, and sometimes we had to move cards around.